# Is there a way to get the expression in a string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, reflection, system.reflection

```
LogEvents(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(queryPlaces.ToBson))
```

I want to be able to output not just the content of System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(queryPlaces.ToBson) but also the actual string of `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(queryPlaces.ToBson)` itself, perhaps with line numbers and file names.

I know that I can do this easily with objective-c. How can I do that with .net?

I've heard that that's what reflextion is for. But how?

There is no macro in vb.net right?